# MongoDB aggregation sum according to document value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to create a mongo db view from two collections with a new value that is a sum of values from one of the collection according to an operation from another collection.
Below is the structure:

```
/* First collection */
{
  "product": "test",
  "labels" : [
    {"code": "label1", "value": 42},
    {"code": "label2", "value": 50}
  ]
}

/* Second collection */
{
  "code": "label3",
  "calculation" : [
    {"label" : "label1", "operation":"+"},
    {"label" : "label2", "operation":"-"}
  ]
}
```

In my aggregated collection i want a new field that would be label1 - label2.

```
{
  "product" : "test", 
  "labels" : [
    {"code": "label1", "value": 42},
    {"code": "label2", "value": 50}
  ], 
  "vlabels" : [
    {"code": "label3", "value": -8}
  ]
}
```

Comment: With which condition do you want to join them? first collection doesn't have "label3" reference and second collection doesn't have "test" reference

Comment: @TheeSritabtim i don't have a join condition. I want something like an uncorrelated subquery lookup. Get all the codes in the second collection, calculate the value for each of them and put them in a new key in the aggregated collection. I'm not sure if it's possible also. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is possible. I doubt it would be optimal, if you don't need further processing on the database, I suggest you do this at the application layer.

However, I have attempted to do this as an exercise. This approach would check only for the `"-"` operator and assign a negative value, other operator will use the existing value.

```
/* First collection: "products" */
/* Second collection: "vlabels" */
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "vlabels", // lookup calculation from vlabels
      let: {
        labels: "$labels"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $set: {
            calculation: {
              $map: {
                input: "$calculation", // map over calculation in vlabels
                as: "calc",
                in: {
                  operation: "$$calc.operation",
                  product: {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$$labels", // filter for matching product labels and get the first element using $arrayAlemAt to get the value
                          as: "label",
                          cond: {
                            $eq: ["$$calc.label", "$$label.code"]
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      0
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: false,
            code: "$code",
            value: {
              $reduce: { // reducing by adding all values in calculation array, use negative value on "-" operator
                input: "$calculation",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {
                  $add: [
                    "$$value",
                    {
                      $cond: [
                        {
                          $eq: ["-", "$$this.operation"]
                        },
                        {
                          $multiply: [
                            -1,
                            { $ifNull: ["$$this.product.value", 0] }
                          ]
                        },
                        { $ifNull: ["$$this.product.value", 0] }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "vlabels"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e-7zNxfiScH)

Comment: this seems ok, the only problem is that you assume that every vlabels in the second collection is found for every product in the labels collection. If one is not found the result would be null.

Comment: @CiprianStanciu you can wrap it in `$ifNull` expression, I have updated the code accordingly